# C Macros: How to map another macro to variadic arguments?

Tags: c, macros

I'd like to know how to apply a unary function (or another macro) to variadic arguments of a macro, like

```
int f(int a);

#define apply(args...) <the magic>
apply(a, b, c)
```

which unrolls

```
f(a)
f(b)
f(c)
```

Note that the number of arguments is unknown.

Answer (score 6):

The code below is working for what you've asked for with up to 1024 arguments and **without** using additional stuff like boost. It defines an `EVAL(...)` and also a `MAP(m, first, ...)` macro to do recursion and to use for each iteration the macro `m` with the next parameter `first`.

With the use of that, your `apply(...)` looks like: `#define apply(...) EVAL(MAP(apply_, __VA_ARGS__))`.

It is mostly copied from [C Pre-Processor Magic](http://jhnet.co.uk/articles/cpp_magic). It is also great explained there. You can also download these helper macros like `EVAL(...)` at this [git repository](https://github.com/18sg/uSHET/blob/master/lib/cpp_magic.h), there are also a lot of explanation in the actual code. It is variadic so it takes the number of arguments you want.

But I changed the `FIRST` and the `SECOND` macro as it uses a Gnu extension like it is in the source I've copied it from. This is said in the comments below by @[HWalters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3936002/h-walters):

> Specifically, 6.10.3p4: "Otherwise [the identifier-list ends in a ...] there shall be more arguments in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...)".

**Main function part:**

```
int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   apply(a, b, c) /* Expands to: f(a); f(b); f(c); */

   return 0;
}
```

**Macro definitions:**

```
#define FIRST_(a, ...) a
#define SECOND_(a, b, ...) b

#define FIRST(...) FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define SECOND(...) SECOND_(__VA_ARGS__,)

#define EMPTY()

#define EVAL(...) EVAL1024(__VA_ARGS__)
#define EVAL1024(...) EVAL512(EVAL512(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL512(...) EVAL256(EVAL256(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL256(...) EVAL128(EVAL128(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL128(...) EVAL64(EVAL64(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL64(...) EVAL32(EVAL32(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL32(...) EVAL16(EVAL16(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL16(...) EVAL8(EVAL8(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL8(...) EVAL4(EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL4(...) EVAL2(EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL2(...) EVAL1(EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define DEFER1(m) m EMPTY()
#define DEFER2(m) m EMPTY EMPTY()()

#define IS_PROBE(...) SECOND(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
#define PROBE() ~, 1

#define CAT(a,b) a ## b

#define NOT(x) IS_PROBE(CAT(_NOT_, x))
#define _NOT_0 PROBE()

#define BOOL(x) NOT(NOT(x))

#define IF_ELSE(condition) _IF_ELSE(BOOL(condition))
#define _IF_ELSE(condition) CAT(_IF_, condition)

#define _IF_1(...) __VA_ARGS__ _IF_1_ELSE
#define _IF_0(...)             _IF_0_ELSE

#define _IF_1_ELSE(...)
#define _IF_0_ELSE(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define HAS_ARGS(...) BOOL(FIRST(_END_OF_ARGUMENTS_ __VA_ARGS__)())
#define _END_OF_ARGUMENTS_() 0

#define MAP(m, first, ...)           \
  m(first)                           \
  IF_ELSE(HAS_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__))(    \
    DEFER2(_MAP)()(m, __VA_ARGS__)   \
  )(                                 \
    /* Do nothing, just terminate */ \
  )
#define _MAP() MAP

#define apply_(x) f(x);
#define apply(...) EVAL(MAP(apply_, __VA_ARGS__))
```

---

To test macro expansion it is useful to use gcc with the command line argument `-E`:

```
$ gcc -E srcFile.c
```

because your're getting concrete error messages and understand what's going on.

Comment: `FIRST` as shown here relies on non-standard gnu extensions.  This implementation, per the standard, requires two arguments; your use of it requires `FIRST` to accept one argument.  `#define FIRST(...) FIRST_(__VA_ARGS__,)` `#define FIRST_(x, ...) x` is a fix.  Similar with `SECOND`.

Comment: Also, `HAS_ARGS` is at best poorly named; it's not really testing if it is passed no arguments.  Rather, it's testing whether its first argument is empty.

Comment: @HWalters: Thank you! As I said it's mostly copied from the source I've mentioned in the answer. I didn't get why `FIRST` should not work for all compiler/preprocessors and why your version is a fix for that? "My version" just throws aways the `__VA_ARGS__` why this is an gnu extension?

Comment: Specifically, 6.10.3p4: "Otherwise [the identifier-list ends in a ...] there shall be more arguments in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the ...)".  (I know you asked for a link, but the text fits in a comment).  `FIRST(a, ...)` thus requires at least two arguments.  Accepting 1 is a gnu extension tied to its comma elision feature.

Comment: @HWalters: Thank you very much got it and changed it! @ZhaoxiongCui: There was also another little error as it expanded to: `f(a); , f(b); , f(c);` with commas in between before. Now the expansion works and it expands to: `f(a); f(b); f(c);`.

Comment: Hi @Xhaoxiong if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is possible in C if you throw enough ugly macros at it. For example, you can have an ugly function-like macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f (int a)
{
  printf("%d\n", a);
}

#define SIZEOF(arr) (sizeof(arr) / sizeof(*arr))

#define apply(...)                    \
{                                     \
  int arr[] = {__VA_ARGS__};          \
  for(size_t i=0; i<SIZEOF(arr); i++) \
  {                                   \
    f(arr[i]);                        \
  }                                   \
}

int main (void)
{
  apply(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Notice that 1) This would be much better off as a variadic *function*, and 2) it would be even better if you get rid of the variadic nonsense entirely and simply make a function such as

```
int f (size_t n, int array[n])
```

Comment: may use `do{...}while(0)` when defining apply.

Comment: @fzyzcjy Depends on the context. If the aim is to produce high quality C code, then no - high quality C code doesn't use `if() x(); else` without braces `{}` and allowing such code is the only purpose of do-while(0). If the aim is create some portable lib that can be used by all manner of users with diverse code quality standards, then do-while(0) should be used.

Comment: Thank you! I have seldom heard of this kind of explanation

Comment: @fzyzcjy This is the reason why MISRA-C dropped the requirement of using do-while(0). It was required for function-like macros in older versions of MISRA, but they dropped the rule in the latest version, because MISRA-C already got the requirement that we must always use braces after all control and loop statements.