# Editing input elements to a function

Tags: c, macros

Can a macro `test` be defined so that `test(a, b, c)` is replaced by `test(G(a), G(b), G(c))`, and similarly for any number of arguments?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to define a macro `test` such that `test(a, b, c)` is replaced by `test(G(a), G(b), G(c))`?

Comment: what is `macro` achieving when `test(G(1), G(4.00), G("Hello world"));` is passed and converted to `test(1, 4.00, "Hello world");` ?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil Yes, I want test (a, b, c) to be converted to test(G(a), G(b), G(c))

Comment: @TruthSeeker I create a dictionary and I just want to put the arguments, and the program added a macro, I recently study C, is this possible?

Comment: When I pass arguments to test, the data types of these arguments are not known to the functions and therefore I need to convert them

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie thanks

Comment: you can indeed do `#define __test(a,b,c) test(G(a), G(b), G(c))`

Comment: @TruthSeeker thanks a lot, I'll try

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: The text to be recognized for substitution is `test`.

Comment: There are preprocessor hacks that can accomplish the necessary expansions for a finite limit on the number of arguments. There are a number of questions and answers on Stack Overflow dealing with this.

Comment: @TruthSeeker I've one question, it works if we have three args, but how can I do something like this for an unlimited number of arguments

Comment: @Andre Kampling thanks a lot, you solved my problem.

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45586169/4139593)