# How to "map" a variadic macro with boost preprocessor?

Tags: c++, boost, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros, boost-preprocessor

Say I have a macro F:

```
#define F(x) /*...*/
```

and a macro G that takes one or more arguments:

```
#define G(...) /*...*/
```

and I want to write a macro H that takes one or more arguments that expands to G with F applied to each argument:

```
#define H(...) /* G(F(arg1),F(arg2),...,F(argn)) */
```

How can H be implemented with boost.preprocessor ?

For example:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define F(x) A x

#define G(...) B __VA_ARGS__ C

#define H(...) ???

H(X, Y, Z)
```

The final line should preprocess to:

```
B A X, A Y, A Z C
```

What code should replace the `???` ?

**Update:** This similar question [C Macros: How to map another macro to variadic arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45585903/18097497) describes how to do it without boost preprocessor, but mentions `EVAL` and `MAP` from boost preprocessor but I can't seem to find either of those in the documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html  Am I blind?

**Update 2:** I've got it working thanks to @Artyer. For posterity, here is the code of the final solution of the enclosing use case mentioned in the comments (generating comparison operators for a struct):

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#define COMPARISON_H_STRUCT_MEMBER_LOOKUP(member) (_struct.member)

#define COMPARISON_H_COMMA_SEPARATED_MAP(r, macro, i, elem) \
  BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) macro(elem)

#define COMPARISON_H_DECL_TIE_FOR(ClassName, seq)                              \
  inline auto comparison_h_tie_struct(const ClassName& _struct) {              \
    return std::tie(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(COMPARISON_H_COMMA_SEPARATED_MAP,  \
                            COMPARISON_H_STRUCT_MEMBER_LOOKUP, \
                                    seq));                             \
  }

#define DECL_STRUCT_EQ_OPS(ClassName, ...)                                    \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_TIE_FOR(ClassName, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, ==)                                         \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, !=)

#define DECL_STRUCT_CMP_OPS(ClassName, ...)                                   \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_TIE_FOR(ClassName, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, ==)                                         \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, !=)                                         \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, <)                                          \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, >)                                          \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, <=)                                         \
  COMPARISON_H_DECL_OP(ClassName, >=)
```

Example usage:

```
struct TestStruct {
  int member1, member2, member3;
};

DECL_STRUCT_CMP_OPS(TestStruct, member1, member2, member3)

int main() {
  TestStruct a, b;
  for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
      a.member1 = (i / 9) % 3;
      b.member1 = (j / 9) % 3;
      a.member2 = (i / 3) % 3;
      b.member2 = (j / 3) % 3;
      a.member3 = (i / 1) % 3;
      b.member3 = (j / 1) % 3;

      assert((i == j) == (a == b));
      assert((i != j) == (a != b));
      assert((i < j) == (a < b));
      assert((i > j) == (a > b));
      assert((i <= j) == (a <= b));
      assert((i >= j) == (a >= b));
    }
}
```

**Update 3**:  Added `FOR_EACH_I` fix.

Comment: Complex function-like macros should almost always be turned into actual functions. What are these macros really for? Or are you just asking out of curiosity? Curiosity is okay, but then please state it in the question. Otherwise if you have an underlying problem you want to solve then please ask about it directly instead (or your question would be a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm writing a macro in C++17 that takes the name of an aggregate class type (a simple struct) and the names of its members and generates (ADL) definitions of `operator==`, `operator!=`, `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<=` and `operator>=`, by expanding to a `std::tie` over its members.  It's not possible to do that from an actual function, as the list of member names (just identifiers) will fail at name lookup.  They need to be prefixed with `&ClassName::`, what I am using the macro map for.  You can see similar usage of macros in (for example) boost.python or pybind11

Comment: That's a good reason for macros, but it should really be part of the question itself. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each_i.html) to do this "mapping" operation:

```cpp
#define VARIADIC_MAP(r, macro, i, elem) BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i) macro(elem)
#define H(...) G(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(VARIADIC_MAP, F, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

The `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i)` prepends a `,` before every value except the first so this expands to what you want.

Comment: Works, thanks.  I added the enclosing solution as **Update 2**.  Feel free to take a look and share any comments.

Comment: `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(BOOST_PP_DEC(r))` is incorrect; `r` is the repetition point for passing to `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_R`, so it may work but only by accident. You should use `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I ` and `BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(i)`.

Comment: Yes, it was working somehow just by accident (and only on 1.78.0 / Linux.  1.71 Linux and 1.78 Windows for each it doesn't work).  I'll try the FOR_EACH_I solution.